# image above list borders.. probably very easy

Tags: html, css

I probably have one of the easiest questions of the day, but I'm having a hard time finding a direct answer for how to fix it (HTML/CSS -n00b)...

I have in my mark-up an img-tag and under that a div-tag containing an horizontal list.
In the lists ul-CSS I have declared a top and bottom border, the img (which is a .PNG with transparent background) is showed in front of the ul border-top, which is what I want. But for the li-CSS I have border-right for each element to separate them, and this border is in front of the img...

Here you see what I mean:

[image]

Edit:

```
#topLeftImage {
    z-index: 999;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 3px;

#navigationlist li
{
    z-index: 0;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 2px;
    font-size: 75%;
    border-right: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
```

}

So how do I declare the img for it to be showed in-front of that li-border?
And another fast question, can I declare so that the last li-element doesn't get that border-right, since it doesn't have a right-neighbour?

Any tips would be helpful!

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using IE to check the results of these changes you are making? IE's z-index method is a little mental. Try the code below and see if that helps.

```
#topLeftImage {
    z-index: 999;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 3px;
    position:relative;
}

#navigationlist li {
    z-index: 0;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 2px;
    font-size: 75%;
    border-right: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
    position:relative;
}
```

and give the parent of these two items:

```
#parent {
    z-index: 0;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: That did it! It was the absence of positioning that threw the z-index off! Thanks a lot!

Comment: no worries. Essentially IE calculates z-index for items that have explicit positioning. You need to specify the parent as well so that both elements start from the same base level.

Comment: yea, the parent was the body and I specified that as well. however, I use FF so it seemed to be a "problem" there as it would be in IE as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `z-index:9999;` for the img if you give it a class and/or set the `z-index:0;` for the li's class.

e.g.

```
img.className {
   z-index:9999;
}

li.className {
   z-index:0;
}
```

Or if you use ID's:

```
img#idName {
   z-index:9999;
}

li#idName {
   z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the css property z-index should help for the first problem.

```
img{
   z-index:999;
}
```

That should make it appear above everything.

(IMPORTANT... Be careful with this though... The whole area of the image will be displayed on top of the nav, making it impossible to click the Item one hyperlink.)

For the latter question, you can use last-child pseudo class to set the right border to nothing. eg.

```
#nav li:last-child{
  border-right:none;
}
```

This is a CSS3 feature... so IE8 and below will not let it work. Maybe just adding a class to the last item will be the most browser friendly way!

```
#nav li.last{
  border-right:none;
}

<li>normal</li><li class="last">furthest right</li>
```

Let me know if the z-index advised by me and another guy causes the problem I outlined. There will be some solutions to this but require a little bit of effort!

Comment: Thanks! The last tip to evade the border worked great! But for the z-index.. I tried to set z-index: 999; to my img-id in the CSS, didn't do any changes, also tried giving the li-id z-index: 0; in the CSS but that didn't help either. I suppose you can use this z-index with id's as well and not only with classes? (I'll put the code in an edit)

Comment: Yep, you can use it with ID's as well as classes but remember if it is an ID use `img#idName{ z-index:9999; }` and if it is a class use: `img.idName{ z-index:9999; }`

Comment: yea, thanks. It looks right to me but it doesn't seem to do it.. have tried setting z-index 0 and -1 to my li and my ul, as well as setting 999 to my image, doesn't do anything.. really weird.. but I'll keep trying, maybe work around it. Thanks for the help! (unfortunately I have too little reputation to rate you guys up... =)

Comment: Is #topLeftImage an ID assigned to the image itself or is it assigned to a div that contains the image? And as I said it'll probs make the nav unclickable anyway! Now I know this may sound a bit hackish, but the best way may be to slice the image in two, have the top part as the logo image and the bottom part as a background image in the ul element. You'll have to do some lining up but it'll work for now and you could look into changing it later :)

Comment: Hey, thanks man. The reason for the z-index not taking effect was that both img and li were un-positioned. Giving them relative positioning did what I wanted. And you were right, the links are virtually impossible to click! =)  So I might just try that last tip you gave about slicing the img. Thanks again m8!

Answer (score 0):

in your code you use `z-index`, and correctly, but you have to keep in mind that `z-index` works *only* with positioned elements. So in both `#navigationlist li` and `#topLeftImage` add `position:relative;`

Comment: That did it! It was the absence of positioning that threw the z-index off! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndroidHustle I am glad for it. You can upvote and accept any question that helped you :)